# Latex newcommand with three input parameter

Tags: macros

I ask this just out of curiosity.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, noheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\doublespacing

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{wrapfigure}{\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}}
\newcommand*\longName[1]{\par{\raggedright\textbf{#1}\par}}
```

I use the following several times about 40-50 times. Is there a way that I define a command with 3 different input parameter. Each time the `Long name text`, the `figure location` and the `Lorem Ipsum text` changing. My input would be something like this: `\myThreeParam{long name text}{figure location}{Lorem Ipsum text}` or is there another way.

```
\longName{Long name text}

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0pt}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{example-image-a}
\end{wrapfigure}

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.\newline
```

**The whole document**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, noheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\doublespacing

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{wrapfigure}{\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}}
\newcommand*\longName[1]{\par{\raggedright\textbf{#1}\par}}

\begin{document}

\longName{Long name 1}

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0pt}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{example-image}
\end{wrapfigure}

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.\newline


\longName{Long name 2}

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0pt}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{example-image-b}
\end{wrapfigure}

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.\newline

\end{document}
```

Comment: it is much easier to answer if you provide test documents not disconnected fragments, but here what have you tried, this seems to be  standard `\newcommand\myThreeParam[3]{...#1...#2...#3}`

Comment: I have just added the whole document.

Comment: I wouldn't use `*`

Comment: Off-topic: `left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm` may be staeted more succinctly as `margin=2.5cm`.

Comment: The `\BeforeBeginEnvironment{\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}}` instruction can be replaced by `\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This calls for an environment rather than a three-argument command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, noheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{mywrap}{mO{scale=0.8}m}
 {\par{\raggedright\bfseries #1\par}\nopagebreak
  \begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0pt}
  \includegraphics[#2]{#3}
  \end{wrapfigure}
  \noindent\ignorespaces
 }{\par}

\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{mywrap}{Long name 1}[scale=0.8]{example-image}
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting 
industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text 
ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of 
type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived 
not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, 
remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with 
the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and 
more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker 
including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text 
of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the 
industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown 
printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen 
book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into 
electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was 
popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing 
Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software 
like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
\end{mywrap}

\begin{mywrap}{Long name 1}[width=3cm]{example-image}
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting 
industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text 
ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of 
type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived 
not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, 
remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with 
the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and 
more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker 
including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text 
of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the 
industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown 
printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen 
book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into 
electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was 
popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing 
Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software 
like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
\end{mywrap}

\end{document}
```

I added an optional argument to pass options to `\includegraphics`, so you can locally override the default `scale=0.8`. With `\nopagebreak` we can avoid the long text to be in a page and the paragraph in the following one.

[image]

Comment: `{\raggedright\bfseries #1}\par` you sure about that `\par` position? :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oops!

Answer (score 4):

It's not really clear what your question is as you already demonstrate `\newcommand` and this is just another example. Unrelated, never end a paragraph with `\newline`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, noheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\doublespacing

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{wrapfigure}{\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}}
\newcommand*\longName[1]{\par{\raggedright\textbf{#1}\par}}
\newcommand\myThreeParam[3]{%
\longName{#1}%
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0pt}%
    \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{#2}%
\end{wrapfigure}%
#3\par}

\begin{document}

\myThreeParam{Long name 1}{example-image}{%
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.} %NO!!!!\newline


\myThreeParam{Long name 2}{example-image-b}{%
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.} %NO!!!!\newline

\end{document}
```

Comment: Then I am gonna use either `\mbox\newline` or `~\newline`

Comment: @mala97 What? The former does nothing (if you're lucky), the latter is plain wrong for it can produce a spurious empty line. In order to terminate a paragraph just leave a blank line in the input.

Comment: @mala97 don't do either!!! Both would be worse than the already bad `\newline`